# Local NuGet Gallery server fails to send email

Tags: email, nuget-server

Has anyone been able to get a Local NuGet Gallery running, and able to send the account confirmation email? I've been able to get the server functioning fine on a local SQLExpress DB, but I can't seem to get the emails to send from the system.

They use some library called anglicangeek.markdownmailer which I can't seem to locate any information about.

If anyone has a tip, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Did you configure the email settings in the database?

Comment: Ahh...no? Where exactly would the settings be located in the DB? I didn't read anything about configuring it during setup.

Comment: There is a table, without looking, I *think* it is called "GallerySettings".

Comment: I found it last night...I entered in my open relay server, but unfortunately it still won't send email :(. It never generates a message in the EmailMessages table either...I would expect one to be there. Thanks again!

Comment: You ever figure this one out?  I'm setting up a local NuGet Gallery and it is not trivial at all.

Comment: No, I gave up on the NuGet Gallery completely. That thing is a trainwreck! It's a system that should be so insanely simple, but yet you end up with this super complex layered approach. We went back to using a file share and just scrapped the idea of hosting an internal gallery :(.

Answer (score 1):

Find, uncomment, and add value based on format explained in the web.config of the NugetGallery

```
<add key="Gallery.SmtpUri" value="" />
```